# Matlab: adapting myODEfun for the 'Vectorized' propery of odeset

Tags: matlab, vector, ode

I have a stiff system of coupled ODEs that I am feeding MATLAB's `ode15s` solver. It works well, but now I'm trying to optimize the speed of integration. I am modeling 5 different variables on `N` different spatial sites, giving 5N coupled equations. For the moment, `N=20` and integration time is about 25s, but I would like to go to larger values of `N`.

I used the profiler to see that the vast majority of the time is spent evaluating `myODEfun`. I did my best to optimize the code, but that doesn't change the fact that there is quite a bit going on in the function and that it is being evaluated ~50,000 times. I read that using the `'Vectorized'` property for the `ODEfunction` can reduce the number of evaluations needed.

But I don't quite understand what exactly it is that I need to change about my `ODEfun` to make it conform to what Matlab wants a `'vectorized'` `ODEfun` to look like.

[From the documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1023074) I see that you can change the example Van der Pol system from its normal form:

```
function dydt = vdp1000(t,y)
dydt = [y(2); 1000*(1-y(1)^2)*y(2)-y(1)];
```

to the vectorized form:

```
function dydt = vdp1000(t,y)
dydt = [y(2,:); 1000*(1-y(1,:).^2).*y(2,:)-y(1,:)];
```

I don't understand exactly what this new matrix of `y` is supposed to represent, and how the size of the second dimension is even defined. I could almost live with just adding "`,:`" and not thinking about it, but I am running into problems because I am already doing some vector operations in my code.

Here is a simplified example of my current functions, not yet `vectorized`. It models 2 variables, making `2*N` equations. Please don't try to make sense of the ODEs that are generated here: they don't. I am talking about the operations that are happening.

```
function dydt = exampleODEfun(t,y,N)

dydt = zeros(2*N,1);
dTdt = zeros(N,1);
dXdt = zeros(N,1);

T = y(1:N);
X = y(N+1:2*N);

a = [T(2:N).^2 T(2:N) ones(N-1,1)];
b = [3 5 -2];

dTdt(1:N) = 0;
dXdt(1) = 0;
dXdt(2:N) = a*b';

dydt(1:N) = dTdt;
dydt(N+1:2*N) = dXdt;

end
```

Obviously in the real function a lot more is going on, both for `T` and `X`. As you can see, `dXdt(1)` is a boundary condition and needs its own calculations.

Blindly passing odeset `'Vectorized','on'` and just adding "`,:`" to all the indexes does not work. For example, what size do I need to initialize `dTdt` and `dXdt` to now? What do I do to the `ones(N-1,1)`? And what do I need to do to make (`a*b'`) still make sense?

I am using Matlab R2006a.

Comment: R2006a, wow....that takes me back :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `help odeset`:

> Vectorized - Vectorized ODE function  [ on | {off} ]
>
> ```
> Set this property 'on' if the ODE function F is coded so that 
> F(t,[y1 y2 ...]) returns [F(t,y1) F(t,y2) ...].
> ```

For the van der Pol example:

without vectorization:

```
function dydt = vdp1000(t,y)             %// 'y' is passed as [y1 
                                         %//                   y2]

    dydt = [y(2);                        %// 'dydt' is computed as [y1´
            1000*(1-y(1)^2)*y(2)-y(1)]   %//                        y2´]
                                         %// where the ´ indicates d/dt
```

*with* vectorization:

```
function dydt = vdp1000(t,y)            %// 'y' is passed as [y11 y21 y31 ...
                                        %//                   y12 y22 y32 ...] 

    dydt = [y(2,:);                             %// 'dydt' is computed as 
            1000*(1-y(1,:).^2).*y(2,:)-y(1,:)]; %//   [y11´ y21´ y31´ ...
                                                %//    y12´ y22´ y32´ ...]
```

where the `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, etc. refer to different vectors `y` at the same time `t` that `ode15s` will use to compute the next step.

For your example, you have to take into account that the `y` you get passed is no longer a vector, but a matrix in which every column represents a different vector you need to compute the derivative of:

```
function dydt = exampleODEfun(t,y,N)

    %// Adjust sizes to meet size of y
    dydt = zeros(2*N, size(y,2));
    dTdt = zeros(N, size(y,2));
    dXdt = zeros(N, size(y,2));

    %// Adjust indices to extract proper vales of ALL vectors
    T = y(1:N,:);
    X = y(N+1:2*N,:);

    %// This sort of section is usually where all the "thought" goes into:
    %// you can't use a*b' anymore, so I sum over the third dimension of the 
    % 3D array I built from your original vector
    b  = [3 5 -2];
    ab = sum(cat(3, b(1)*T(2:N,:).^2, b(2)*T(2:N,:), b(3)*ones(N-1, size(y,2))), 3);

    %// and finish it off
    dTdt(1:N,:) = 0;
    dXdt(1,:) = 0;
    dXdt(2:N,:) = ab;

    dydt(1:N,:) = dTdt;
    dydt(N+1:2*N,:) = dXdt;

end
```

Comment: Thanks, the key insight I was missing is that the matrix is composed of different vectors for `y` at the _same_ `t`. But that doesn't explain _why_ there are different solutions fed through the `ODEfun` for the same time. Surely in the end there is only one solution for every `t`. My guess would be that the solver computes multiple possible solutions for `y` and the process of deciding which one to use somehow requires execution of the `ODEfun`?

Comment: @PietdeBakker: `ode15s` uses the Jacobian (`df/dy`) to compute steps. If you can't compute or otherwise do not have explicit values for the Jacobian, `ode15s` will estimate the Jacobian through [finite differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). This process involves evaluating `f(t,y)` for many `y` at the same `t`.

Comment: @PietdeBakker: In other words: another way to speed up your problem is by deriving and implementing the problem's Jacobian. See `help odeset` for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The basic step of suppling the solver with a JPattern for the problem has cut the computation time spent in my function by 80%. And that is without vectorizing.